# How can I add a raspberry to a touchscreen car dvd unit?

Tags: raspberry-pi, automotive, touchscreen, stereo

I am working on converting a Toyota 2-din touch screen dvd stereo unit into a car computer. I would like to add a raspberry to it and be able to have the raspberry display a browser on the touch screen and accept inputs. And also use the raspberry to control bluetooth and read usb sticks. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For what your asking. It would be either a involved piggyback or a gutting of the original system.

For the piggyback it would be finding a way to insert a video signal. E.g. some in car dvd systems have a hdmi input. Or at a minimum a reversing camera input.

If that works then its just hijacking the touchscreen data when your in that mode. Most of these devices ignore the touchscreen while in reverse. So hooking into the outputs from the controller may give you the touch data.

Bluetooth would be finding the chip responsible and putting it into a sleep or reset mode. Or if you want to play man in the middle have the pie emulate that chip and connect with its own bluetooth. Usb might be using a kvm style usb switch so in the pie mode it has access to the usb but not the dvd player

If none of that is an option. Your on to gutting.

First point would be to reverse engineer or find the work of someone who has previosly done it for the protocol and pinout of the display. From there you may be able to reuse some existing code library or have to tweak one to suit so you can display to it. This may involve logic level shifting if it expects different voltage levels

Next up is the buttons / touchscreen. Buttons can probably be mapped to general I/O without issue. Touchscreen should just involve working out what controller to talk to it.

Then bluetooth and usb would be the easy parts.